# Visual studio, C: Warnings do not point to the correct line

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, warnings

I have written a code in VS in C language, and when it types out warnings/errors, it always points to a wrong line. Also, when debugging, the cursor points at a wrong line.
Can anyone help me and tell me what's the cause for this?
Thanks

Comment: For start, it would be good to see the code. Is it define/macro?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your code is actually compiling and that the files you are looking at in VS are the ones that VS is trying to compile?

Comment: @tilz0R It's not define nor macro, it's in functions outside the main. The code is too long for me to send it (1000 lines)

Comment: @Jackson can you elaborate?

Comment: I've seen this kind of thing when the executable you are debugging doesn't match the code in the editor, usually because the compile is failing and the debugger is running the last working version of the code.  You need to provide the shortest piece of code you can that shows the issue if you want more help - however I suspect that creating an example to post will probably show you how to resolve the issue.  Good luck!

Comment: @Jackson I will try to include a snippet of the code in a couple of minutes. But if that's the case, what's a good fix for it? Is copying the code into another project and running it there going to work?